# template class without a name in c++

Tags: c++

I have two parallel classes, one which parses .xlsx files, and one which parses xls files.
I wrote the xlsx parser myself, but inherited from another xls parser to fit it into my class model. So far, so good.

Both classes end up using the same piece of code using rapidjson to create a json array for insertion to the db. However, on the xlsx side, everything works, but on the xls side, the inclusion and use of the rapidjson library give rise to the following error:

```
excelparser/lib/rapidjson/rapidjson.h:370:1: error: template class without a name
```

Even if I remove all the code from xls.cpp and only leave a simple #include in xls.h I have the same error.

The lines in the header file are :

```
//! UTF-16 encoding.
/*! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16
    \tparam CharType Type for storing 16-bit UTF-16 data. Default is wchar_t. C++11 may use char16_t instead.
    \implements Encoding
*/
template<typename CharType = wchar_t>
struct UTF16 {                                    // <-- Line 370
    typedef CharType Ch;

    static Ch* Encode(Ch* buffer, unsigned codepoint) {
        if (codepoint <= 0xFFFF) {
            RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(codepoint < 0xD800 || codepoint > 0xDFFF); // Code point itself cannot be surrogate pair 
            *buffer++ = static_cast<Ch>(codepoint);
        }
        else {
            RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(codepoint <= 0x10FFFF);
            unsigned v = codepoint - 0x10000;
            *buffer++ = static_cast<Ch>((v >> 10) + 0xD800);
            *buffer++ = (v & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00;
        }
        return buffer;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that it would be MUCH easier to solve this if we could see line 370 in this header file [and perhaps 5-10 lines above and below]...

Comment: There you go. Added the bit that is failing.

Comment: Run it through the preprocessor, just to be sure there aren't any illicit macros in place.

Comment: Agree with Kerrek - there's probably some macro that defined UTF16 to "nothing". (Or add `#ifdef UTF16 #error #endif` as three new lines before template on line 369.

Comment: ok that #ifdef made an error occur, but the preprocessor works with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root-cause of the problem is that the external xls parser is using a macro `UTF16` that expands to an empty string.

This conclusion can be reached through the following deduction process:

- Both the xls and the xlsx parsers use the `rapidjson.h` header file, but only the xls parser (which uses the external library) has problems, so the external library is a contributing factor.
- The error message from the compiler indicates the text `UTF16` somehow disappeared.
- The code snippet

  ```
  #ifdef UTF16
  #error
  #endif
  ```

  produces an error due to tripping on the `#error` directive. Both of these indicate that a preprocessor marco with the name `UTF16` is in play.

There are a few ways to resolve these kinds of errors:

- Reorder the `#include` directives such that the header that causes the macro to exist gets included after `rapidjson.h`.
- Add to the beginning of the `rapidjson.h` header the line

  ```
  #undef UTF16
  ```

  to ensure the macro does not exist when processing the file.

Note that include guard can not help agains this kind of problem, because it is caused by interference between two different headers (from different libraries even), not because a single header got used multiple times (this is what header guards protect you for).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write this here for posterity, and chalk it up to inexperience.

The crucial detail I had utterly forgotten about was that both classes inherited a pure virtual class called spreadsheet, for pointer related reasons.

Adding the #include "rapidjson.h" to the spreadsheet.h and remove it from both xls.h and xlsx.h solved the problem.

The thing I don't understand is that I thought include guards were supposed to prevent this.